# How to compile android layout XML into bin(raw/binary) using android aapt?

Tags: android, aapt

Android uses one of its build tool AAPT(Android Asset packaging Tool) to compile and zip resources etc into APK. I want to use AAPT to compile just one resource file(xml) and save it in my computer.I read many blogs but didn't find any command to do that. Please help me with this.

command will be something like this:-

```
aapt /*some syntax*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows you can use [Android Tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/android-tools/) to decompile apk and edit/save the xml.

And compile it back to an apk file.

How to :

1. Drag the apk file into apk Editor list box
2. Select the apk then press decompile button, wait it till finished decompiling.
3. After that go to the apk project folder find the XML you want to edit.
4. If you done, close all folder than compile it back into an apk file.
5. Sign the apk.
6. Done. You can install it directly using Application Tools by pressing install button and select the signed apk.